# ¿Cómo guardar el resultado de un comando externo ejecutado en Python?

Tags: python, linux, redes, awk

Estoy escaneado mi rango de red para encontrar todos los dispositivos que tengan el puerto 80 abierto y si este se encuentra abierto enviarle una petición con python requests y escribir el banner grabbing en un archivo.

```
rang = "192.168.0.1/24"
ip = os.system("sudo nmap -Pn %s -p80 --open | awk '/is up/ {print up}; {gsub 
(/\(|\)/,\"\"); up = $NF; NR==1}'" %(rang))
r = requests.get("http://%s"%(ip))
```

Quiero tomar cada una de las direcciones como variables y enviar las peticiones pero la salida son todas las ip's en simultanea y no permite enviar las peticiones.

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.12
192.168.0.23
....
```

Answer (score 4):

Al fin y al cabo lo que estás buscando es la manera de ejecutar un comando externo en Python y guardar su resultado para ejecutar una acción contra cada uno de sus valores.

Para ello, usa el módulo [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) de Python. En particular, usando la función [`check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
>>> resultado =subprocess.check_output("seq 10 | awk '1'", shell=True)
>>> resultado
b'1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n'
```

Nótese que uso un comando más simple para simplificar la redacción:

```
$ seq 10 | awk '1'
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Como ves, el resultado es todo una string, por lo que puedes usar `splitlines()` para convertirlo en una lista:

```
>>> a.splitlines()
[b'1', b'2', b'3', b'4', b'5', b'6', b'7', b'8', b'9', b'10']
```

Todo junto, lo que puede servirte es:

```
rang = "192.168.0.1/24"
ips = subprocess.check_output("sudo nmap -Pn %s -p80 --open | awk '/is up/ {print up}; {gsub 
(/\(|\)/,\"\"); up = $NF; NR==1}'" %(rang))
for ip in ips.splitlines():
   r = requests.get("http://%s"%(ip))
```